# Is it possible to load a VBA code from a file located in a network folder?

Tags: excel, vba, directory, working-directory

I have a .vba file located in a network folder let's call it `helloworld.vba` inside this file I have a sub function `HelloFromTheOtherSide()`.

I'm trying to programmatically load this file in a way that I can execute the functions `HelloFromTheOtherSide()` in my excel instance.

Imagine that this is the content for simplicity:

```
Sub HelloFromTheOtherSide()
MsgBox ("hello there!")
End Sub
```

I've tried to follow these instructions [on how to dynamically add and run a VBA macro from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/219905/how-to-dynamically-add-and-run-a-vba-macro-from-visual-basic) but that is not what I'm trying to do here as I want to be able to run calling `HelloFromTheOtherSide()`.

**I'm trying to understand if its possible to load a .vba from a folder to an excel instance programmatically in a way I could run the functions in my instance.**

That would be quite usefull if possible as I would be able to store all my vba code in a single folder and load it from there everytime that I want to run something specific.

Comment: That is about what the example does: it loads the macros in an instance of excel and you can call them in that instance.

Comment: I'm unsure if this would work for a .vba file, but it does work for .bas files (exported macros):  `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import FILEPATH\FILENAME.BAS` which then allows you to call the macro which is now part of your current workbook.

Comment: Could you not just have a module file n your network folder? that way you can include the module when you open the workbook. This also means that you can make changes to the module and all workbooks using the module will always have the latest code

Comment: You could use an addin also maybe?

Comment: @Zac I'm still learning VBA... so didn't understood much on your proposal but if you can give me more details or give me a link so I can learn more that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both **VBA** or **VBScript** to call a `Function` or a `Sub` from another `Workbook`:

### VBA

```
Sub callExternalFunction()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object

    'Define Excel App
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'Open Workbook
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\server\my\path\to\My library.xlsm", 0, True)

    'Call my Sub, with eventual parameters (if you don't have any, just call the Routine)
    xlApp.Run "Myfunction", "param_1", "param_2"

    'Quit and clean
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

### VBScript

```
Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
    Dim xlApp
    Dim xlBook

    'Define Excel App
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'Open Workbook
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("R:\my\network\path\My Workbook.xlsm", 0, True) 

    'Call my Sub, with eventual parameters (if you don't have any, just call the Routine)
    xlApp.Run "myRoutine"

    'Quit and clean
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

### Edit

You can omit the Excel App initialization and directly call the Macro you need with this command *(thanks to @TimWilliams)*:

```
Application.Run "'MyBook.xls'!MyMacroName"
```

> **Note**: As you can see they are pretty similar. Both codes are tested and working on my Excel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for this...I've tried the .vbs option. When I run the code I get "cannot run the macro `HelloFromTheOtherSide`". The macro may not be available in this workbook...". Is there anything else that I need to add to the vbs file? Currently I'm only adding the sub function

Comment: @costargc You're welcome. Check if the name is correct (Uppercase counts) and take a look at the updated answer. :)